# How to roll a PrintWriter output file if size gets too large?

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm using PrintWriter to write to an output file, but I'm dealing with a lot of data. The file size can get absurdly huge because of this, so I'd like a way to output to several files if the size of one gets too large. But it doesn't seem like there's a supported way to do this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Sure there's a supported way: Close it and create a new one for writing to the new/next file. But, it sounds more like you're creating a log file, and if so, why not use a logging library, which has features like that built-in?

Comment: I sort of tried this. I had a StringBuilder that also appended the lines to it. When it exceeded a certain size, I closed the printwriter, set it to a new one, and cleared the StringBuilder (I couldn't seem to find a way to keep track of the length of the output file). It works but I feel the solution is a little dubious. I've used log4j before, but I don't know how to use a proper RollingFileAppender for standard text files (not HTML)

Comment: It is not a silly question at all. I'm facing the same problem and ended up with making a PrintWriter wrapper enapsulating the rolling logic. There are example like https://github.com/bmc/javautil/blob/master/src/main/java/org/clapper/util/io/RollingFileWriter.java or https://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/io/RollingFileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `write(String s, int off, int len)` method to write just a portion of data. Opening multiple output stream and tuning `offset` and `len` parameters you should be able to distribute data in multiple files.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: I believe question is about many writes that over time will end up creating a huge file, not the splitting of a since `print()` call.